# jest-haste-map: Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, watchman

I just found an error while running the metro of react native
it came after upgrading the os

the error was

```
    jest-haste-map: Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler.
  Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanconfig` file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in your project.
  Error: Watchman error: std::__1::system_error: open: /Users/dongjae/Desktop/wellCupOfficial/wellcupOfficial/wellcupApp: Operation not permitted. Make sure watchman is running for this project. See https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.
/Users/dongjae/Desktop/wellCupOfficial/wellcupOfficial/wellcupApp/node_modules/metro-hermes-compiler/src/emhermesc.js:77
          throw ex;
```

after googling it and trying some soulutions for 3hours? i found that i had to add "watchman" to Full Disk Access under Security&Privacy

Also I found that watchman is in dir    opt/local/bin/watchman
However, the biggest problem is that I have found no way to access to this folder
I can't even see this folder in the selecting window
Please help this poor developer..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

try this it worked for me

```
$ watchman watch-del-all
$ watchman shutdown-server
```

Comment: why does this work?

Comment: This didn't work for me

Answer (score 13):

In the root of your project, run `watchman watch-del-all`,
then run `watchman shutdown-server`. The next time you run the app you will be prompted to give access to watchman. This should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will be helpful. worked for me.

You should move the entire project directory outside of the Documents or Download directory for mac

https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/977

Answer (score 1):

Try to move outside the Desktop folder. I've moved my projects to my User folder, and everything works.

Strange, yes. But at least at the moment, I can continue coding.

Comment: This is working, but as you said it's strange.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS I had to run `sudo yarn start` it worked and the system showed an alert to give watchman read rights, after accepting `yarn start` can run normally without sudo.

Answer (score -2):

Reset your project

> git reset --hard

Delete Node modules if you have to

Comment: You'd also want to check watchmanconfig file if there are any breaking changes